# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle user picture Upload

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to add a profile picture to my User entity in a symfony2 project using FOSUserBundle. I already worked with symfony2 file upload process i only have an upload and database persist problems when i used FOSUserBundle.

Here is my Entity :

```
namespace ICGM2\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="user")
*/
class User extends BaseUser
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true) 
 */
public $path;

/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000") 
 */
public $file;

/*     * *************************************************************** */

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist() 
 * @ORM\PreUpdate() 
 */
public function preUpload()
{
    if (null !== $this->file) {
        $this->path = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $this->file->guessExtension();
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist() 
 * @ORM\PostUpdate() 
 */
public function upload()
{
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }
    $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);
    unset($this->file);
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostRemove() 
 */
public function removeUpload()
{
    if ($file == $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->path;
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadDir() . '/' .
            $this->id . '/' . $this->path;
}

protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/' . $this->getUploadDir() . '/' . $this->id;
}

protected function getUploadDir()
{
    return 'uploads/users';
}

   /**
 * Set path
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @return User
 */
public function setPath($path)
{
    $this->path = $path;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get path
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPath()
{
    return $this->path;
}
```

....

And the Form : UserType.php

```
  $builder->add('file', 'file', array(
        'required' => false
    ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi if anyone had the same problem here his the solution.
I changed some functions in the User Entity :

```
   /**
 * @param UploadedFile $file
 * @return object
 */
public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    // set the value of the holder
    $this->file = $file;
    // check if we have an old image path
    if (isset($this->path)) {
        // store the old name to delete after the update
        $this->t = $this->profilePicturePath;
        $this->tempPath = null;
    } else {
        $this->path = 'initial';
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get the file used for profile picture uploads
 * 
 * @return UploadedFile
 */
public function getFile()
{

    return $this->file;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist() 
 * @ORM\PreUpdate() 
 */
public function preUpload()
{
    if (null !== $this->getFile()) {
        // a file was uploaded
        // generate a unique filename
        $filename = $this->generateRandomProfilePictureFilename();
        $this->setPath($filename . '.' . $this->getFile()->guessExtension());
    }
}

/**
 * Generates a 32 char long random filename
 * 
 * @return string
 */
public function generateRandomProfilePictureFilename()
{
    $count = 0;
    do {
        $generator = new SecureRandom();
        $random = $generator->nextBytes(16);
        $randomString = bin2hex($random);
        $count++;
    } while (file_exists($this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $randomString . '.' . $this->getFile()->guessExtension()) && $count < 50);

    return $randomString;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist() 
 * @ORM\PostUpdate() 
 */
public function upload()
{
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }
    $this->getFile()->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->getPath());

    if (isset($this->tempPath) && file_exists($this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->tempPath)) {
        unlink($this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->tempPath);
        $this->tempPath = null;
    }
    $this->file = null;
}
```